# Reading lines and columns with different separators from a text file

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a function that reads in individual lines from a text file. Each line has two or three columns. I am want to know most elegant/clean approach for it. I am need the function to work with different separators `(\t,\n,' ',',',';')`.

My approach works correctly except for different separators.

E.g. Input:

```
6
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
10 
0 1 0.47
2 0 0.67
3 0 0.98
4 0 0.12
2 1 0.94
3 1 0.05
4 1 0.22
3 2 0.24
4 2 0.36
4 3 0.69
```

Pattern Input:

```
[total number of vertices]
[id-vertex][\separetor][name-vertex]
...
[total number of edges]
[id-vertex][\separator][id-neighbor][\separetor][weight]
...
*\separetor=\t|\n|' '|','|';'
```

My approach:

```
void readStream(istream& is, const char separator) {
    uint n, m;
    is >> n;
    cout << n << endl;
    string name;
    uint vertexId, neighborId;
    float weight;
    while(!is.eof()) {
        for(uint i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            is >> vertexId >> name;
            cout << vertexId;
            cout << " " << name << endl;
        }
        is >> m;
        cout << m << endl;
        for(uint j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            is >> vertexId >> neighborId >> weight;
            cout << vertexId;
            cout << " " << neighborId;
            cout << " " << weight << endl;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Overview:

1. Problem: Different separators.
2. Others elegantes solutions: In general, someone have other elegant/clean solutions to the problem?

Comment: I do not see the separator character being used in your function at all

Comment: I don't know how to include the separator in my code.

Comment: You can use `std::strpbrk()` function on defined byte string with separators.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I have little knowledge of `c++` `stream`. Could you explain more please?

Comment: You say that “each line has two or three columns”, but the first and eighth lines have only one, and these seem to correspond to the number of following lines up to the next single column line that appears to signify a change in the number of columns of the non-single column lines. It looks like there's more structure to your file than you've indicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my other posting for this scenario: [Override istream operator >> and modify delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907007/override-istream-operator-and-modify-delimiter) (The explanation for this is first variant of the accepted solution here for a possible implementation).

In general one way you could possibly deal with the unwanted separators is to turn them into spaces!

My approach enables the use of new delimiters for operations '>>' from istream:

```
struct delimiterIsSpace : ctype<char> {
    delimiterIsSpace() : ctype<char>(get_table()) {}
    static mask const* get_table() {
        static mask rc[table_size];
        rc[';'] = ctype_base::space;
        rc[','] = ctype_base::space;
        rc[' '] = ctype_base::space;
        rc['\t'] = ctype_base::space;
        rc['\n'] = ctype_base::space;
        return &rc[0];
    }
};
```

How to use:

```
cin.imbue(locale(cin.getloc(), new delimiterIsSpace));

for (int a, b; cin >> a >> b; ) {
    cout << "a=" << a << " b=" << b << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [boost split](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_34_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id1638536) it can split a string on multiple separators that you can specify.

```
std::string = line;
std::vector<std::string> parts;

boost::split(parts, line, boost::is_any_of("\t\n,; "));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use(Considering that your file will always be in the above mentioned format)

```
fstream file;
file.open("abc.txt",ios::in);
int numOfVertices;
string line;
getline(file, line);
numOfVertices = stoi(line);
vector<int> xCoord;
vector<int> yCoord;
while((--numOfVertices)>=0) 
{
    string line;
    getline(file, line);
    std::size_t prev = 0, pos;
    pos = line.find_first_of(" ';", prev);
    xCoord.push_back(stoi(line.substr(prev, pos-prev)));
    prev = pos+1;
    pos = line.find_first_of(" ';", prev);    //considering some of the delimiters
    yCoord.push_back(stoi(line.substr(prev, pos-prev)));
}
```

This is to add the vertices. Similarly you may extract the edges as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure the separator is not white space, you can just throw them into a garbage string (e.g. separator in the case follow)

```
is >> vertexId >> separator >> neighborId >> separator >> weight;
```

Comment: If that were the issue, this question wouldn't be here. He wants to have everything in his separator list treated *as-if it were whitespace*. So "1 2 3", "1 2,3", "1;2 3", "1;2,3" *all* parse to be three integers. (at least thats what I'm getting from the question).

Comment: @WhozCraig can you please see my answer and point out the mistakes if any. Even suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

The following code may be useful:

```
int t1,t2;
double t3;//global variables...
void parse_Vertex_Line(char *str)
{
     int tmp=0;
     char *p=str;
     //extract the vertex-id
     while(*p >='0' && *p <='9')
        tmp = tmp*10 + *(p++) -'0';
     t1=tmp;
     tmp=0;
     p++;
     //now extract the vertex-name..
     while(*p >='0' && *p <='9')
        tmp = tmp*10 + *(p++) -'0';
     t2=tmp;
     return;
}

void parse_Edge_Line(char *str)
{
     //extracting the first two numbers is just the same...
     int tmp=0;
     char *p=str;
     //extract the first vertex-id
     while(*p >='0' && *p <='9')
        tmp = tmp*10 + *(p++) -'0';
     t1=tmp;
     tmp=0;
     p++;
     //now extract the second vertex-id..
     while(*p >='0' && *p <='9')
        tmp = tmp*10 + *(p++) -'0';
     t2=tmp; 
     p++;
     //but extracting a double value is a bit different...
     //extract the weight...
     int before_decimal=0, after_decimal=0;
     while(*p!='.')
         before_decimal = before_decimal*10 + *(p++) -'0';
     p++;
     int no_of_digits=0;
     while(*p>='0' && *p<='9')
     {
         after_decimal = after_decimal*10 + *(p++) -'0';
         no_of_digits++;
     }
     //assign it to the global double variable...
     t3 = before_decimal + (after_decimal/pow(10.0, no_of_digits));
}
```

Now what you do is first get the `number of vertices(n)`. Next read each of the `n` lines. 
Calling the function `parse_Vertex_Line` each time. Then read the `number of edges` and similarly call `parse_Edge_Line` each time. Extract the values and Store them.

This code works for almost any delimiters. Hope this looks elegant to you.

Comment: It's a very “manual” C solution. Not that there's necessarily anything wrong with that, under the right circumstances, but it's not what I'd describe as an elegant answer to this question in *C++*, which is how it's tagged.